# Change the installation path with msi API

Tags: c, deployment, installation, windows-installer

I'm trying to set installation path manually, with these lines of code,

```
MSIHANDLE msiHandle;
UINT openPackageExitCode = MsiOpenPackage(LR"(path to .msi file)", &msiHandle);
LPCTSTR newPath = LR"(C:\test\)";
UINT changePathResult = MsiSetTargetPath(msiHandle, L"INSTALLDIR", newPath);
MsiCloseHandle(msiHandle);
```

but, I get an error which says `ERROR_DIRECTORY`.

How can I change the installation path with this method?

Comment: I'd make sure this custom action is getting called after CostFinalize. Before that, the Directory table hasn't been processed.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `MsiSetTargetPath` in a custom action after `CostFinalize` action solved my problem.